# Custom Objects Reports and Custom Fields

Tags: reporting, custom-object, custom-field, roll-up-summary

We have a custom object called 'Buildings' we already are using the declaritive tool for rollup fields bc of the M-D relationship issue to Accounts and Opportunities.

We are looking to build a report with Building information as well as the number of Closed Won Opportunities that have not been installed yet (Customer Installation Completed Date) field is blank. We are looking for a total running number of Opps that meet this criteria. Perhaps I can map this number to the account easily and then use my declaritive tool from the appexchange to do the rollup?

In addition, it would be beneficial to be able to easily tell which opportunities are the ones that meet this criteria specifically as well.

Comment: Opps are on the detail side of a M-D relationship with Accounts, so if you can relate them back to the Account, you can easily roll them back up to Buildings as you currently are with Accounts or you can roll them up directly from Opps using the same roll-up tool. In either case, it's going to require another calculation that's done separately each time you save a Building record.

Comment: Would this require a formula field in the Opps formula = IF Closed Won & Customer Installation Completed Date is equal to null then COUNT ?

Comment: In what context are you asking me about the formula? Are you referring to the declarative roll-up tool? If so, I don't use it on a regular basis to answer your question, but that sounds reasonable as a date field would be null, *but* could also be read as "isEmpty" or "isBlank" depending on the tool's options (isEmpty is usually preferred by SF) . I typically am asked to write triggers using code instead of following the declarative approach.

Comment: what is the schema between Accounts and Buildings, Opportunities and Buildings?

Comment: The Building sits above the Accounts (rolls up using this declarative tool) then Opps under the accounts-